# passing in a parameter to AppFunc

Tags: c#, .net, owin

I am following [this article](http://benfoster.io/blog/how-to-write-owin-middleware-in-5-different-steps) for understanding OWIN and with respect to points 3 and 4 in there would want to know how to pass a parameter to the Logging constructor so I can pass it in to the owin framework as shown in point #4.

I have created the AppFunc alias using this line of code:

```
using AppFunc = Func<IDictionary<string, object>, Task>;
```

What is that expression on the right of the equal sign even called?

So now my constructor is like this

```
    public LoggingMiddleware(AppFunc next, MyDependency dependency)
    {

    }
```

now how do I create the object?

In Point #3, it says I can add a dependency object to the constructor and gives an example of how to register it using the type name. In point #4 in the article it says that you can also create an instance in advance and pass it in when registering but then it doesn't explain how to create the constructor. I tried this and did not work

```
LoggingMiddleware lmw = new LoggingMiddleware(new Func<"","">(),depObj);
```

I want to create a constructor of LoggingMiddleware so I can register it to the OWIN framework using this line

```
var logger = new LoggingMiddleware(????);
app.Use(logger);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking.  Isn't this covered by the link?  It says to register using `app.Use(typeof(LoggingMiddleware), new MyDependency())`

Answer (score 1):

The `AppFunc` is provided by the framework, so you don't create it.

Per part 3, if you want to use a *type*, the `AppFunc` is injected into the constructor.

Per part 4, if you want to use an *instance* you don't inject the `AppFunc` as a dependency, you have another `Initialize` method.

You could probably combine the two:

```
public class LoggingMiddleware
{
    private AppFunc next;

    public LoggingMiddleware(AppFunc next, MyDependency dependency)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public void Initialize(AppFunc next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(IDictionary<string, object> environment)
    {
        await next.Invoke(environment);
    }
}
```

And use as a *type* like so:

```
app.Use(typeof(LoggingMiddleware), depObj);
```

And use an an *instance* like so:

```
var logger = new LoggingMiddleware(null, depObj);
app.Use(logger);
```

Comment: ok that worked. But I was trying to register the same middleware using both ways: 1.) like the way you have done above and also like this.. 2.) app.Use(typeof(LoggingMiddleware), new LoggingMiddleware());

Comment: Is it possible to do it like that?

Comment: I've updated with something that should work for both.

Comment: would I be missing something if I pass in a null in the constructor there? It seems to be an important parameter which might pass context in from a previous middleware component.

Comment: ok I tried the option you gave above for working it with both, but I got an error:>>>  No conversion available between System.Func`2[System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object],System.Threading.Tasks.Task] and System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.Object].
Parameter name: signature

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  I tried what I wrote both ways in a new web application and had no issues.

Comment: Not really sure what to suggest.  It certainly works as-is on the `Microsoft.Owin` implementation.